# vite errors when built with components of chakra UI

Tags: vite, chakra-ui

I am trying to use Chakra UI with ReactJS in a Vite built project.
I have not been able to integrate them together. Whether I use an older or newer version of Chakra

I am the following Vite and Chakra UI versions, but when I run a vite build I get errors seen below.

```
  "@chakra-ui/core": "^0.8.0",
   "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.8.2",
   "react": "^18.2.0",
```

```
Error
psd-ui/node_modules/@chakra-ui/theme/dist/chakra-ui-theme.esm.js:20:2
18: 
19: var styles = {
20:   global: function global(props) {
      ^
21:     return {
22:       body: {
```

If I upgrade Chakra to the latest version for React 1.8, I get a different error

```
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.5.1",
uild started...
✓ 430 modules transformed.
Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
file: /Users/rpvp/Work/PostOffice/psd-etl/psd-ui/node_modules/@chakra-ui/theme/dist/chunk-I4WK6NDQ.mjs:3:2
1: // src/styles.ts
2: var styles = {
3:   global: {
     ^
4:     body: {
5:       fontFamily: "body",
```

Anyone facing this issue and can suggest a fix, potentially in the Vite config file which is below

```
import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import rollupNodePolyFill from "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills";
import { splitVendorChunkPlugin } from "vite";
import commonjs from 'vite-plugin-commonjs'
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

dotenv.config(); // load env vars from .env

export default defineConfig({
  //mode
  define: {
    // By default, Vite doesn't include shims for NodeJS/
    // necessary for segment analytics lib to work
    global: '({})',
  },

  root: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
  //base: '/' - OS default of
  publicDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
  build: {
    target: "modules",
    minify: "esbuild",
    cssCodeSplit: false,
    emptyOutdir: true,
    assetsDir: "myAssets",
    watch: {
      include: "src/**",
    },
    
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.html"),
      },
      //default: index vite root / index.html
      output: {
        format: "es",
        entryFileNames: "[name].[hash].[format].ini.js",
        chunkFileNames: "[name].[hash].[format].chunk.js",
        assetFileNames: "[name].[hash].asset.[ext]",
      },
      plugins: [
        resolve(),
        commonjs(),
        rollupNodePolyFill(),
        splitVendorChunkPlugin(),
      ],
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "./runtimeConfig": "./runtimeConfig.browser", // <-- Fix from above
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error while building using npm run build cmd in vite application

Add this code to your vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
  },
})
```

Refer [ChakraUI Vite](https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started/vite-guide#3-customizing-theme-optional)